# Why C++ is called federation of languages?

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-languages

I was reading a tutorial on C++ and the following line came up. No other details were provided to explain further

> C++ is a "federation of languages" and supports multi-paradigm programming, there are many options available to us.

What does it mean when C++ is called federation of language and also what is multi-paradigm programming?

Comment: Effective C++ by Scott Meyers , Item1 explains why we should view C++ as a federation of languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the explanation from *Effective C++ Third Edition 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs 
By Scott Meyers*, ***Item 1: View C++ as a federation of languages***.

> Today's C++ is a multiparadigm programming language, one supporting a
>   combination of procedural, object-oriented, functional, generic, and
>   metaprogramming features. This power and flexibility make C++ a tool
>   without equal, but can also cause some confusion. All the "proper
>   usage" rules seem to have exceptions. How are we to make sense of such
>   a language?
>
> The easiest way is to view C++ not as a single language but as a
>   federation of related languages. Within a particular sublanguage, the
>   rules tend to be simple, straightforward, and easy to remember. When
>   you move from one sublanguage to another, however, the rules may
>   change. To make sense of C++, you have to recognize its primary
>   sublanguages. Fortunately, there are only four:
>
> - **C**. Way down deep, C++ is still based on C. Blocks, statements, the preprocessor, built-in data types, arrays, pointers, etc., all come
>     from C. In many cases, C++ offers approaches to problems that are
>     superior to their C counterparts (e.g., see Items 2 (alternatives to
>     the preprocessor) and 13 (using objects to manage resources)), but
>     when you find yourself working with the C part of C++, the rules for
>     effective programming reflect C's more limited scope: no templates, no
>     exceptions, no overloading, etc.
> - **Object-Oriented C++**. This part of C++ is what C with Classes was all about: classes (including constructors and destructors),
>     encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual functions (dynamic
>     binding), etc. This is the part of C++ to which the classic rules for
>     object-oriented design most directly apply.
> - **Template C++**. This is the generic programming part of C++, the one that most programmers have the least experience with. Template
>     considerations pervade C++, and it's not uncommon for rules of good
>     programming to include special template-only clauses (e.g., see Item
>     46 on facilitating type conversions in calls to template functions).
>     In fact, templates are so powerful, they give rise to a completely new
>     programming paradigm, template metaprogramming (TMP). Item 48 provides
>     an overview of TMP, but unless you're a hard-core template junkie, you
>     need not worry about it. The rules for TMP rarely interact with
>     mainstream C++ programming.
> - **The STL**. The STL is a template library, of course, but it's a very special template library. Its conventions regarding containers,
>     iterators, algorithms, and function objects mesh beautifully, but
>     templates and libraries can be built around other ideas, too. The STL
>     has particular ways of doing things, and when you're working with the
>     STL, you need to be sure to follow its conventions.

Comment: The quality of Scott Meyer's books never cease to amaze

Comment: I do wish though that he would stop calling the C++ Standard Library the "STL".

Comment: @Bathsheba Why?

Comment: @songyuanyao: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library

Comment: @Bathsheba I think he just meant "STL", not the whole standard library.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Still, I don't see how separable it is; particularly from C++11. The standards make no attempt at a separation. That whole page needs an update anyway, now we have `constexpr` programming.

Answer (score 4):

"Federation of languages" means the big breadth of diverse features and ways to apply the C++ language.

Multiparadigmatic languages combined paradigms. Examples are F-Sharp, OCaml and Swift. So it's a group of language-styles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is from Effective C++. The writer is just saying that C++ grammar comes from a series of sub-languages. Read about it [here](http://codeofthedamned.com/index.php/view-c-as-a-federation).

As for multi-paradigm programming, it's the ability of a language to support more than one programming style. This allows flexibility for different tasks. A google search should answer this for you.